# What is the best way to get all webpage links with Html Agility Pack?

Tags: c#

i am try to get all links from webpage with Html Agility Pack, after send web URL (cnn.com) i have this list (return by Html Agility class):

[image]

what is the best way to get all this page links cause some of those links start with "/" and not with the page address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those links that don't start with an `http://` are relative to the current address (`http://cnn.com`) so you could prepend it to get the full address. And for those that represent javascript functions, well, there's not much you could do with HTML Agility Pack as it only parses HTML.

Comment: OK and if after the first parse i want my parse depth to be another one inside my first parse, how can i do it ? HTML Agility Pack get URL and return list

Answer (score 1):

That's what I use in cases like these:

```
protected Uri GetAbsoluteUri(string linkUri)
{
        var uri = new Uri(linkUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        return uri.IsAbsoluteUri ? uri : new Uri(PageUri, uri);
}
```

The code above assumes that:

- `linkUri` is the value of an anchor's `href` attribute
- `PageUri` is a `System.Uri` object that represents the Absolute Uri of the current page